# select option url rewrite htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want help in .htaccess my current url is give below

```
http://searchbankifsccode.com/state.php?bnakname=ABHYUDAYA%20COOPERATIVE%20BANK%20LIMITED
```

I want to rewrite this url as

```
http://searchbankifsccode.com/ABHYUDAYA-COOPERATIVE-BANK-LIMITED
```

please help me on it.
I tried below code

I tried following rewrite rule in my .htacess file but nothing happens

- `RewriteRule ^([^/\0-9]+)$ state.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`
- `RewriteRule ^index/([^/\0-9]+)$ index.php? [NC,L]`
- `RewriteRule ^state/ ([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ state.php? [NC,L]`

  and
  I have may RewriteEngine On

Comment: And you have tried something???

Comment: How will you know that the request should go to `state.php`?

Comment: Because i am sending that value on that state.php page the option value is -                                      <option value="./state.php?bnakname=<?php echo $row["bank"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["bank"]; ?></option> ----- (on selecting the bank from dropdown)

Comment: I tried the following code in my .htaccess file but nothing works              RewriteRule ^index/([^/\0-9]+)$ index.php? [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^state/ ([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ state.php? [NC,L]

Comment: The `.htaccess` is for all requests though. What happens with the rule you tried? Please add that to the question.

Comment: I tried following rewrite rule in my .htacess file but nothing happens     ------------ RewriteRule ^([^/\0-9]+)$ state.php?id=$1 [NC,L]-------------RewriteRule ^index/([^/\0-9]+)$ index.php? [NC,L]------------------------
RewriteRule ^state/ ([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ state.php? [NC,L] -------------but that dosent help.

Comment: Please add it to the question, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47391778/edit. Do you have the engine on? `RewriteEngine On`. You are using apache? Are you getting any errors?